# Jenkins with Shared jobs

Tags: jenkins

I am working with Jenkins, and we have quite a few projects that all use the same tasks, i.e. we set a few variables, change the version, restore packages, start sonarqube, build the solution, run unit/integration tests, stop sonarqube etc.  The only difference would be like {Solution_Name}, everything else is exactly the same.

What my question is, is there a way to create 1 'Shared' job, that does all that work, while the job for building the project passes the variables down to that shared worker job.  What i'm looking for is the ability to not have to create all the tasks for all of our services/components.  It be really nice if each of our services/components could have only 2 tasks, one to set the variables, another to run the shared job.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially benefit from looking into the new pipelines as code feature.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

Using this pattern, you define your build pipeline in a groovy script rather than the jenkins' UI.  This script is then kept in the codebase of the project it builds in a file called Jenkinsfile.

By checking this pipeline into a git repository, you can create a minimal configuration on the jenkins' side and simply tell it to look towards a specific repo and do the things that pipeline says to do.

There's a few benefits to this approach if it works for your setup.  The big one being that your build pipeline will be fully versioned just like the project it builds.  And the repository becomes portable, easily able to be built on any jenkins' installation across as many jobs as long as the pipeline plugins are installed.

Comment: I do like this idea of Pipeline, this might help, my concern is that we have at least 50 components, and 30 services, that use the exact same configuration, if we put all the scripts in the projects, and then we change the build process, then we would need to go to all 80 of these projects to update the script.

Comment: I would rather all of our build scripts to reside in one place, not in each individual project.  Our build process is changing frequently right now, as we just added sonarqube, we will be adding more things in the future.  In the past year, we have changed our build process at least 5 times, and currently we have to updated all 80 jobs to include the new tasks, we would have to do the same thing if we used a script.  I am trying to get away from modifying so much just because we wanted to add a new step to our build process.

Comment: and to clarify, when i say project, i mean solution.

Comment: Yeah, that can get difficult.  One (maybe hacky) solution could be to let the pipeline live in it's own repository and set up a webhook merge job in jenkins that will go and merge it into each project every time a push is made to the pipeline's repo, updating each project's old version.  You would still have to create that affiliation with every project, but at least only once

Comment: Interesting, I will look into this, as that might be an option.